# On load event not triggering for <object> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `object` tag in my HTML which embeds a PDF. I want to do something after the PDF is loaded (stop a modal loader)

I have tried this but it only works in Firefox and doesn't work in Chrome. I would like any possible solution in either vanilla JS or jQuery.

```
<object id="pdf-preview" type="application/pdf" data="/admin/get_pdf"></object>
```

```js
$("#pdf-preview")[0].addEventListener('load', function (e) {
  alert("Loaded")
  stopLoader();
});
```

The event is not triggered in Chrome at all!

Comment: Have you determined the point of failure? In other words, is the event not being raised in Chrome, or is there an error in `stopLoader()` itself?

Comment: Yes the event is not triggered in Chrome.. works perfect in Firefox

Comment: I don't believe the `load` event is part of the spec for `object` elements so the fact it works at all in Firefox is surprising. You may be out of luck here.

Comment: Can you please put it in **jsfiddle**?

Comment: Is there any other thing that i can do.. any alernative? to check whether the object tag loads the pdf

Comment: @FirozTennali on it

Comment: @FirozTennali i cannot make a fiddle because it doesn't allow me to embed a PDF from any source.. it gives me the mixed content error

Comment: There is apparently no workable solution for Chrome: it simply does not fire the `load` event when a PDF is loaded in an `<object>` element. However, have you considered embedded the PDF in an `<iframe>` element by the `src` attribute instead?

Comment: will it trigger the load event if i use an Iframe?

Comment: @Terry Yes it works with an Iframe. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Please post the solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have mentioned in my comment, the `<object>` element no longer fires the `onload` event in Chrome. After some testing, it only fires the `onload` event handler in non-Chromium/Webkit browsers (e.g. Firefox and Edge).

A quick rundown on some basic browser tests I have made:

- Fires the `load` event: Firefox and Edge
- Does not fire the `load` event: Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE11

A workaround will be to load the PDF in an `<iframe>` element via the `src` attribute:

```
<iframe id="pdf-preview" src="/admin/get_pdf"></iframe>
```

And then you can easily bind the `load` event listener as such:

```
document.getElementById('pdf-preview').addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    console.log('Loaded', e);
});
```

If you prefer to use jQuery, you can also do this:

```
$('#pdf-preview').on('load', function(e) {
    console.log('Loaded', e);
});
```